# Variables not being pulled from GET

Tags: php, html, sql

I have an sql statement that uses php variables, but they don't seem to be getting pulled from the URL through a GET. Here are my variables:

```
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$firstseason = $_GET['firstseason'];
```

Then I have my URL:

```
np2pp2.php?firstname=t9&lastname=t9&firstseason=1900
```

When my SQL statement runs, I get this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT playerID 
FROM players WHERE firstname='' AND lastname='' AND firstseason=' at line 2
```

So it looks like it's not pulling the variables, but I don't know why. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I should have added the SQL query:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

       SELECT playerID, $year, '$team', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
         $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
         $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm FROM players WHERE firstname='$firstname' 
       AND lastname='$lastname' AND firstseason=$firstseason";
```

Comment: What is the SQL query?

Comment: How are you building this query? Can you show the PHP code for it?

Comment: You seem to have skipped the most important part of the code which is where you *use* the variables....

Comment: This is the full query:

$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

       SELECT playerID, $year, '$team', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
         $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
         $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm FROM players WHERE firstname='$firstname' 
       AND lastname='$lastname' AND firstseason=$firstseason";

Comment: Not sure how to make that into a code block, sorry.

Comment: your code should work , give a try to $_REQUEST.

Comment: when you echo those variables, they are not empty ?

Comment: Why you are using PHP variables in your query ($year, '$team', $gp, ...)?

Comment: Are you sure you want the *variables* `$year`, `$team` etc? Don't they refer to database fields rather than PHP variables?

Comment: Your SQL is also really open to injection right now, look into using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

when including variables in your query always put inside curly brackets like:

```
select * from table where year = '{$year}'
```

see if that helps

also if you don't you code is much more inject-able.

Answer (score 1):

First, double-check that the $_GET variables are populating by throwing an if statement up top:

```
if ($firstname != "" && $lastname != "" && $firstseason != "") {
    // do SQL
} else {
    // output error
}
```

If that shows you the error, try:

- echoing the variables
- echoing the $_GET items directly
- using $_REQUEST instead of $_GET

Also, your SQL may need quotes around '$firstseason'.

Comment: Verifying the variables contain nothing like this will still be throwing loads of warnings in PHP (undefined index)... instead you should use `isset($_GET['firstname'])` etc.

Comment: That depends on how your environment is set up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)
       SELECT playerID, year, team, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
       asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm 
       FROM players WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' 
       AND lastname='".$lastname."' AND firstseason='".$firstseason."'";
```

If the values in the select statement are php variables you need to use ''.

```
SELECT playerID, '".$year."', '".$team."', '".$gp."', '".$minutes."', '".$pts."'
```